Spring Boot Consumer service unable to connect EventHub's consumer group
Have created two consumer groups in Eventhubs service, each consumer group used by different services,
Consumer group 1 name is $Default -> used by Service 1 with 1 instance running in AKS
Consumer group 2 name is "match_tool_cg"  -> Used by Service 2 with 1 instance running in AKS
Both consumer group points the same topic, suddenly Eventhub returs below error.
[Consumer clientId=consumer-$Default-1, groupId=$Default] Node -1 disconnected
Tried by restarting the services, and killed the Service 2 pod and running only service 1 which uses $Default, still error persists, unable to connect the Eventhub.
What could be the issue.  It was working earlier without any issues.

does my solution works for you?

In each Event Hub there will be a 4 partitions and you are using 1 consumer group.

Partitions : 4

Non-Epoch Receivers per Partition : 5

Total Non-Epoch Receivers : 4 partitions * 5 receivers = 20 receivers


In this above scenario, you can have up to 20 non-epoch receivers in total for the consumer group, with each receiver being able to read from one of the 4 partitions.

If you exceed this above limit, additional receivers will be disconnected. This is what happened in the below scenario.


Both consumer group points the same topic, suddenly Eventhub returs below error.
[Consumer clientId=consumer-$Default-1, groupId=$Default] Node -1 disconnected

Check the Event Hub metrics for any cause of throttling, quota exceeded errors, or other issues.
Note: Optimise partitions and scale up the number of TUs to handle higher ingress and egress rates.
